# Session variable is not storing sometimes

Tags: php, session

In my File A :I start a session and create few session variables.

Then I go to my File B: same project and start a new session. However some session variables are available and one is not available all the time ? The unstored on is an associative array.

Any feedback on this ?

**File A** :

```
$data = [
            'teacher_id' => $_SESSION['user_id'],
            'mobile' => $_POST['mobile']];    
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
   session_start();
}

        $_SESSION['advert'] = $data;
```

**File B** :

```
public function validate(){
        if(!isset($_SESSION)){
            session_start();
        }

        print_r($_SESSION['advert']);
    }
```

Comment: Hi I just updated the question with the code

Comment: `session_start()` should go to the most top of your page.. just without `if(!isset($_SESSION)){....}`

Comment: However when I print_r($_SESSION) in the File B given space it prints all Sessions variables within however not the one I stored in File A.

Comment: We need to know where and how you're using `validate()`. I suspect a possible variable scope. In any case, enable error reporting and tell us what it reveals.

Comment: Use $_SESSION['advert'] = serialize($data) and unserialize($_SESSION['advert'] to fetch the data